# Calling view function from another view - Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following views in my application. Basically I want to call show_house() in App.MapView when the li of the App.HouseListElemView is clicked.

What would be the best way of doing this?

```
App.HouseListElemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        'click': function() {
            // call show_house in App.MapView
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#house-list-template').html());
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var html = this.template({model: this.model.toJSON()});
        $(this.el).append(html);
    },   
});

App.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '.map',
   events: {
       'list_house_click': 'show_house',
   },
   initialize: function() {
       this.map = new GMaps({
           div: this.el,
           lat: -12.043333,
           lng: -77.028333,   
       });
       App.houseCollection.bind('reset', this.populate_markers, this);
   },
   populate_markers: function(collection) {
       _.each(collection.models, function(house) {
            var html = 'hello'
            this.map.addMarker({
                lat: house.attributes.lat,
                lng: house.attributes.lng,
                infoWindow: {
                    content: html,
                }                
            });
       }, this);
   },
   show_house: function() {
       console.log('show house');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current house is really part of your application's global state so create a new model to hold your global application state:

```
var AppState  = Backbone.Model.extend({ /* maybe something in here, maybe not */ });
var app_state = new AppState;
```

Then your `HouseListElemView` can respond to clicks by setting a value in `app_state`:

```
App.HouseListElemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    events: {
        'click': 'set_current_house'
    },
    set_current_house: function() {
        // Presumably this view has a model that is the house in question...
        app_state.set('current_house', this.model.id);
    },
    //...
});
```

and then your `MapView` simply listens for `'change:current_house'` events from `app_state`:

```
App.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'show_house');
        app_state.on('change:current_house', this.show_house);
    },
    show_house: function(m) {
        // 'm' is actually 'app_state' here so...
        console.log('Current house is now ', m.get('current_house'));
    },
    //...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sXFLC/1/

You might want `current_house` to be an actual model rather than simply the `id` of course but that's easy.

You'll probably be able to find all sorts of other uses for `app_state` once you have it. You can even add a little bit of REST and AJAX and get persistence for your application settings pretty much for free.

Events are the usual solution to every problem in Backbone and you can make models for anything you want, you can even make temporary models strictly for gluing things together.

Comment: +1. Excuse my ignorance, but what is the difference between this method/appstate and extending [Backbone.Events](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) for traditional PubSub?

Comment: @TyroneMichael: Easy persistence for the most part. PubSub just routes information around and forgets about it, a model remembers and makes it easy to persist the state to your server.

Comment: Great thanks! Ya and makes sense to keep your states in an object instead of floating around your code. Interesting pattern.

Comment: Then would it make sense to have all the views inherit from a master View?

Comment: @Trip: That's one of those *it depends* things, sometimes it make sense, sometimes it doesn't.